# is there a replacement for image_picker in flutter? because i cant use image_picker and barcode_scanner at the same time

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there is a replacement or any other method on uploading images in flutter with PHP backend without using image picker?
because for some reason I cant use barcode scanner if I am using image picker. I don't know if my question is clear or not. I hope someone get what I am asking. Thanks!!!

I already tried removing barcode scanner dependency, if I do so, the image picker is working and vice versa.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart'.
i have image_picker: ^0.6.7+22 on my pubspec.yaml file but still it says target URI doesnt exist. but if i removed " barcode_scan: ^3.0.1 " on my pubspec.yaml file it will work. 
it seems like i have to choose between the two of them to be included in my app, but the thing is i need both of them. hope this helps